# calculate the balance amount and insert another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help on building an sql query, I have below two queries, I want to combine the sum of debit substracted from credit and then insert result as balance into another table

```
select sum(amount)
from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS
where CUSTOMER_USER_NAME='55555' and transaction_type='credit' and account_type='customer' and IS_DELETED='false' 

select sum(amount)
from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS
where CUSTOMER_USER_NAME='55555' and transaction_type='debit' and account_type='customer' and IS_DELETED='false'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when transaction_type = 'credit' then amount when transaction_type = 'debit' then - amount end) as balance
from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS
where CUSTOMER_USER_NAME = '55555' and
      account_type = 'customer' and
      IS_DELETED = 'false' ;
```

You would then insert this into another table using `insert`, although I'm not sure how a single value in a single row would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Could use CROSS APPLY

```
select a.*, b.CreditSum, c.DebitSum
from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS a
cross apply
   (select sum(amount) as CreditSum
    from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS
    where CUSTOMER_USER_NAME='55555' and transaction_type='credit' and account_type='customer' and IS_DELETED='false'
    ) b
cross apply
   (select sum(amount) as DebitSum
    from ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS
    where CUSTOMER_USER_NAME='55555' and transaction_type='debit' and account_type='customer' and IS_DELETED='false'
    ) c
where a.CUSTOMER_USER_NAME='55555' and a.account_type='customer' and a.IS_DELETED='false'
```